# 404 Not found node

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

Hi so I have been using this node server for some time and it recently stopped working (presumably due to some logical error I mistakenly adjusted), throwing a 404 when I run the server. When I call on it with an http request it throws a 404 as well and shows the same on load from the actual URL in a browser. What is going on?

[image]

[image: en[![enter image description here]ter image description here][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Cvs.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Cvs.png)

index.js:

```
//Environment Vars
var uri = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
console.log(uri + " environment")

//Express App
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Api for reading http post request body in express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Log Connections
app.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('incoming connection . . . ')
  console.log(req)
  next()
})

//API middelware
var api = require('./api')
app.use('/api', api)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Welcome!', success: true, error: null }));
}); 

//Create Server
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

api.js

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

var stripe_key = process.env.STRIPE_KEY || "sk_test_P9XQtrrfGYU9mF8h6C47bgUp"
var stripe = require('stripe')(stripe_key);
var request = require("request-promise-native")

//API
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'API Gateway', success: true, error: null }));
}) // Just for testing, just for error-handling

//1. Create a customer account
router.post('/new_customer', function (req, res) {
  console.log("Creating new customer account...")
  var body = req.body

  stripe.customers.create({ email: body.email, })
    .then((customer) => {
      console.log(customer)
      // Send customerId -> Save this on Firebase for later use
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, error: null, customerId: customer.id }));
    })
    .catch((err) => {  
      console.log(err)
      res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: err }))
    });
})

//2. Save Credit Card with token
router.post('/new_card', function (req, res) {
  var customerId = req.body.customerId
  var token = req.body.token

  stripe.customers.update(customerId, { source: token })
    .then((customer) => {
      console.log(customer)
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, error: null }));
    })
    .catch((err) => {  
      console.log(err)
      res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: err }))
    });

})

//3. Use customerId to post a charge
router.post('/new_charge', function (req, res) {
  var customerId = req.body.customerId
  var amount = req.body.amount
  var source = req.body.source
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: amount,           //in cents
    currency: "usd",
    customer: customerId,      //CUSTOMER_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID
    source: source, // obtained with Stripe.js
  }).then((charge) => {
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Sucess.', success: true, error: null }));
  }).catch((error) =>{
    res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Error', success: false, error: error }));
  })
})


router.post('/ephemeral_keys', (req, res) => {
  const stripe_version = req.body.api_version;
  var customerId = req.body.customerId;

  if (!stripe_version) {
    res.status(400).end();
    return;
  }
  console.log(stripe_version)
  // This function assumes that some previous middleware has determined the
  // correct customerId for the session and saved it on the request object.
  stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: customerId},
    {stripe_version: stripe_version}
  ).then((key) => {

    console.log("Ephemeral key: " + key)
    res.status(200).json(key);
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'AAAAhh', success: true, error: null }));
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Ephemeral key error: " + err)
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'ABBBBBB', success: true, error: null }));
    res.status(500).end();
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Other details:

Two important files: index.js & api.js but functionality is all in api.js which is why URL stem goes: .../api/...

Comment: Your `router.post('/new_charge'` is for `POST`, you are trying to do a `GET`.

If you type it in a browser, it'll do the `GET` by default. Try something like `Postman` for Chrome to do a `POST`

Comment: Interesting how the OP **never addresses the details pointed out  in same 4 answers** about something that has "worked for a long time"; but "made an update" to demonstrate the problem actually exists. The real question for the OP is what changed between the time it "worked for a long time" and when it stopped working? I suppose I already know the answer.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I just clarified my response to the answers below and, as accountability was an issue, I clarified that there was an error in the code on my part as well. Please now consider the question at hand.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Use a REST client to test your POST with this URL: https://ColossalNextConference--randycasburn.repl.co/api/ephemeral_keys  and if you want to see the code, go here:  https://repl.it/@randycasburn/ColossalNextConference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok got the issue and its as silly as it can get. Are you sure you started the right server ? Its definitely not the node server. Its the http-server you have started. To start the server through node you need to go into the directory (in the terminal) and write "node index.js". Necessary code to start a http-server is written inside index.js.

Got this from the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the error for me is that you are making a `GET` request on a route that requires a `POST` request:

```
router.post('/new_charge', function (req, res) {
  ...
})
```

So you should check that you are making a post request to this route and not a GET request. How are you accessing that route from the client?

Comment: Hi, I made an update that also shows that the /ephemeral_keys POST does not register despite it being a post request.

Comment: To be clear, our answer is correct. My point is that the same issue is present in legitimate POST requests (note ephemeral_keys)

Answer (score 1):

There is no router.get route for '/api/new_charge', there is one router.post route though.

Comment: Hi, I made an update that also shows that the /ephemeral_keys POST does not register despite it being a post request.

Comment: To be clear, our answer is correct. My point is that the same issue is present in legitimate POST requests (note ephemeral_keys)

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `router.get('/new_charge')` route? it's not in the files you posted. You might have either deleted it or the `/new_charge` route needs to be used as post and not get.

Comment: Hi, I made an update that also shows that the /ephemeral_keys POST does not register despite it being a post request.

Comment: To be clear, our answer is correct. My point is that the same issue is present in legitimate POST requests (note ephemeral_keys)